# Call function again after successful ajax request inside ng-repeat

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I have a function like this:

```
scope.addReply = function(el) {

  createCommentFactory.saveComment(scope.form.reply[el.pivot.comment_id], el.pivot.project_id, el.pivot.comment_id, el.level + 1)
    .success(function(data) {

      //ADD REPLY TO CLIENT SIDE
      scope.comments.splice(scope.comments.indexOf(el) + 1, 0, data);

      //TOGGLE FORM AFTER SUCCESSFUL AJAX REQ
      el.formWhat = !el.formWhat;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

  // RESET REPLY TEXT AREA
  scope.form.reply = "";
};
```

html:

```
<div dir-paginate="x in comments | itemsPerPage: commentsPerPage">
  <form ng-submit="addReply(x)" class="dd animated slideInDown" novalidate>
    <ng-form name="replyForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <text-angular name="replyText<%x.pivot.comment_id%>" ta-default-wrap="span" ta-max-text="600" ta-min-text="15" ta-text-editor-class="form-control myform1-height" ta-html-editor-class="form-control myform1-height" ta-toolbar="[['bold','italics']]" style="min-height: 100px; color:red;" 
                      ng-model="form.reply[x.pivot.comment_id]" required></text-angular>

        <p style="color:red" ng-show="replyForm.replyText<%x.pivot.comment_id %>.$error.taMaxText">
          Text should not be more then 600 characters.</p>
        <p style="color:red" ng-show="replyForm.replyText<%x.pivot.comment_id %>.$error.taMinText">
          Text should be at last 15 characters.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input addreply ng-disabled="replyForm.replyText<%x.pivot.comment_id%>.$invalid" class="btn btn-default pull-right"
               type="submit" value="Send"/>
      </div>
    </ng-form>
  </form>
</div>
```

Function, after ajax is successful, will push item below the comment I reply inside: `scope.comments`... Problem now is that I can't submit form which I added with ajax request because form is not created by `ng-repeat`, for is created after ajax request like this: `scope.comments.splice(scope.comments.indexOf(el) + 1, 0, data);`

Comment: Really not clear what your issue is. Nothing in code shows `unshift()` A demo might help

Comment: My bad, I edit main post... This part adding comment inside `comment` array: `scope.comments.splice(scope.comments.indexOf(el) + 1, 0, data);` after ajax request...

Comment: Still not clear...create a simple demo that replicates problem

Comment: Which part you don't understand? It is easy to understand... After successful ajax request this will push new item to ng-repeat: `scope.comments.splice(scope.comments.indexOf(el) + 1, 0, data);` and `it will create new form`. Problem is I can't submit that new form.